# Resolving data on ui-router and angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material, resolve

I have an app that has a toolbar as in Angular Material suggests. This toolbar has only, for now, a title.

```
<md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h2>
            <span>{{pageTitle}}</span>
        </h2>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

And I have the following structure on my ui-router state configuration:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'nav': {
                    templateUrl: baseUrl + 'home/views/partials/ufa-toolbar.html',
                    controller: 'navController'
                },
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: baseUrl + 'home/views/partials/ufa-content.html',
                    controller: 'ufaController'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                title: function() {
                    return 'Home'
                }
            }
        })
.state('app.accounts', {
            abstract: true,
            url: 'accounts/',
            controller: 'accountsController'
        })
        .state('app.accounts.login', {
            url: 'login',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: baseUrl + 'accounts/views/partials/ufa-login-content.html',
                    controller: 'loginController'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                title: function() {
                    return 'Login'
                }
            }
        })
```

What I want to do is resolve in every child state, the page title. But it seems that the `navController` is loaded once and only. If I navigate through states it won't load again and resolve the `title` as I want to do.

I think it would be possible to use in every child state a view `nav@` referecing to the parent view with its custom `html`. But for now, the effort of creating `html` templates to just change the name doesn't look efficient for me.

The `navController` looks like this:

```
.controller('navController', ['$scope', '$state', 'title', function ($scope, $state, title)
{
    $scope.pageTitle = title;
}])
```

The bottle line: is it possible to resolve a title attribute while changing child states that does not contain its own custom view but it is under a parent state.

Comment: in the `navController` function arguments are not right, it should be `function ($scope, $state, title) { ... } `

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I already edited. But I remove all others parameters to post here. So I missed this one. Thanks anyway.